# Parameter of member functions of template class

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

I am trying to better understand templates and have turned to to the good 'ole matrix class.  I know about eigen, armadillo, etc. my purpose is to better understand templates.  My question is how do you get a member function to take an argument that is an object of the same template class, but with a different specialization?

For example, the matrix class I'm trying to put together takes two template parameters--number of rows and number of columns.  Also, any m x n matrix object (`Matrix<mRows,nCols>`) should be able to take an n x p matrix object (`Matrix<nCols,pCols>`) and multiply them together and return an m x p matrix object (`Matrix<mRows,pCols>`):

```
template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
class Matrix
{
private:
    double matrixData[mRows][nCols];
 //...other stuff
public:
 //...other stuff

   Matrix operator * (const Matrix<nCols, pCols>& rhs);
}

// simple naive matrix multiplication method
template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
Matrix<nCols,pCols> Matrix<mRows, nCols>::operator * (const Matrix<nCols,pCols>& rhs)
{
    Matrix<nCols,pCols> temp();

    for (int r = 0; r<mRows; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0;c<pCols;++c)
        {
            temp.matrixData[r][c]=0;
            for (int elem = 0; elem<nCols;++elem)
            {
                temp.matrixData[r][c]+= matrixData[r][elem]*rhs.matrixData[elem][c];
            }
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

The main function would be something like:

```
int main() 
{
  Matrix<2,3> m1;
  Matrix<3,4> m2;

  //...initialize matrices...

  Matrix<2,4> m3 = m1 * m2;

}
```

This doesn't work because pCols isn't declared anywhere. Where / how should it be declared?

Comment: I do understand that the purpose of this class is the better understanding of templates. But anyway you should always remember that compiler generates code for every template parameters (in opposite to the java generics). That means that if you will use this class in order to multiply matrices ([N, M] * [M, K]) with different sizes then the amount of generated code will also depend on number of unique triplets of sizes ([N, M, K])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing with this for a while I finally have a solution using suggestions from Columbo.  The first solution keeps the multiplication operator as a member function and then makes all specializations friends with each other so they can modify each others private data:

```
template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
class Matrix
{
private:
    double matrixData[mRows][nCols];

public:

    template<unsigned nRows, unsigned pCols> // make all specializations of the templates friends with each other
    friend class Matrix;

    // ... constructor and other operator definitions/prototypes here

    // define proper matrix multiplication
    // should be defined such that Matrix<mRows,pCols> = Matrix<mRows,nCols>*Matrix<nCols*pCols> 
    // since the inner dimensions of the matrix must be the same.
    template <unsigned pCols>
    Matrix<mRows,pCols> operator * (const Matrix<nCols, pCols>& rhs) const;
};

template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
template <unsigned pCols>
Matrix<mRows,pCols> Matrix<mRows, nCols>::operator * (const Matrix<nCols,pCols>& rhs) const
{
    Matrix<mRows,pCols> temp;

    for (unsigned r = 0; r<mRows; ++r)
    {
        for(unsigned c = 0;c<pCols;++c)
        {
            temp.matrixData[r][c]=0;
            for (unsigned elem = 0; elem<nCols;++elem)
            {
                temp.matrixData[r][c]+= matrixData[r][elem]*rhs.matrixData[elem][c];
            }
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

The second solution follows Columbo's suggestion to make the multiplication operator a `friend` non-member function:

```
template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
class Matrix
{
private:
    double matrixData[mRows][nCols];

public:

    // ... constructor and other operator definitions/prototypes here

    // define proper matrix multiplication
    // should be defined such that Matrix<mRows,pCols> = Matrix<mRows,nCols>*Matrix<nCols*pCols> 
    // since the inner dimensions of the matrix must be the same.

    template <unsigned m, unsigned n, unsigned p>
    friend Matrix<m,p> operator * (const Matrix<m,n>& lhs, const Matrix<n, p>& rhs);
};

template <unsigned m, unsigned n, unsigned p>
Matrix<m,p> operator * (const Matrix<m,n>& lhs, const Matrix<n, p>& rhs)
{
    Matrix<m,p> temp;

    for (unsigned r = 0; r<m; ++r)
    {
        for(unsigned c = 0;c<p;++c)
        {
            temp.matrixData[r][c]=0;
            for (unsigned elem = 0; elem<n;++elem)
            {
                temp.matrixData[r][c]+= lhs.matrixData[r][elem]*rhs.matrixData[elem][c];
            }
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

If anyone could comment on why one is better than the other it'd be great.  I think the second solution is better since just that function is specialized for different combinations instead of the entire class (right?). For example in `Matrix<3,3> * Matrix<3,4>` vs `Matrix<3,3> * Matrix<3,5>` the `Matrix<3,3>` class would only need to specialized once and the `* operator` would be specialized to cover both cases. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Make `operator*` a member function template himself. I.e. write inside the class template

```
template <unsigned pCols>
Matrix operator * (const Matrix<nCols, pCols>& rhs);
```

And outside use two parameters lists:

```
template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
template <unsigned pCols>
Matrix<mRows, pCols> Matrix<mRows, nCols>::operator * (const Matrix<nCols,pCols>& rhs)
```

However, I encourage you to use a `friend` non-member function.

Comment: I think this is the right idea--within the class template I had to change the prototype within the class to `template <unsigned pCols>
    Matrix<mRows,pCols> operator * (const Matrix<nCols, pCols>& rhs);`, however I'm getting about not being able to access the private members of the class. Can one specialization of a template not access the private members of a different specialization of that same template?

Comment: @Jason No, why would that be the case? They are different classes.

Comment: If you multiply two `Matrix<3,3>`'s together they can access each other's private members no problem.  However with a `Matrix<3,3>` times a `Matrix<3,4>` apparently you can't do that, but it'd be nice if you could

Answer (score 1):

You have to use template arguments available in your function template definition to specialize the Matrix class, in your case:

```
template <unsigned mRows, unsigned nCols>
Matrix<mRows,nCols> Matrix<mRows, nCols>::operator * (const Matrix<nCols,mRows>& rhs)
```

Then again you're better off using a consistent naming convention for your template arguments in both declaration and definition.

Think of the template arguments as of types/constants available for you to use within the entity that follows it. Declarations are definitions are essentially separate entities in this context (that's why you need to type template<> second time when providing a function definition).

Edit: After reading the question once again carefully, it turns out my answer misses the point. Columbo's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The `operator*` function needs only one template parameter. The number of rows of the RHS has to be the same as the number of columns of the LHS.

```
template <unsigned pCols>
Matrix<nRows, pCols> operator * (const Matrix<nCols, pCols>& rhs)
{
  //...
}
```